# Resize/scale an image with :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have an image with a hover event. The only problem is it does not scale to a smaller size or to mobile screens. I've spent much time researching and haven't found anything. I thought 100% width should have done the trick. I must be missing something.

[Codepen link.](http://cdpn.io/iIxmJ)

Please help before my brain splits.
Also, criticism welcome.

Comment: post your code - dont make people jump thru hoops to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this one:

```
body, html {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.myButtonLink {
background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5869656/Caroline%20Ziv/Home-test3.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #E6E6E6;
display: block;
height: 100%;
text-indent: -99999px;
width: 100%;
background-size: 100%;
}
.myButtonLink:hover {
background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5869656/Caroline%20Ziv/Home-test5.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #E6E6E6;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Also apply below css to the page you have loaded in iframe.

```
body, html {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: It worked out! I would upvote both of you guys but I have no reputation. Thank you so much.

Comment: Rep 15 needed for upvoting, but you can select one as your best answer by checking the tick mark lies left to the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

- Apply `max-width: 100%;` to the `img`
- Remove `text-indent: -9999px;`
- Remove the background image on the `div`

Comment: I would upvote both of you guys but I have no reputation. Thank you so much.